# Chrome Extension: Multiple communication channels with direct messaging

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that listens & displays network requests in a popup. Therefore, there are three JS files that need to communicate. I would like each of these scripts to send messages to each of the others directly. Something like (Though I know this doesnt work)

popup.js:

```js
// Listen to messages to the popup
chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'popup' }).onMessage.addListener(/* Whatever */)
```

background.js

```js
// Listen to messages to the background
chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'background' }).onMessage.addListener(/* Whatever */)
```

devtools.js

```js
// Listen to messages to the devtools
chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'devtools' }).onMessage.addListener(/* Whatever */)
```

I would like to send a message to any of the channels by doing something like

```js
// Send a message to the popup from any script
chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'popup' }).sendMessage(/* Message */)
```

However, I know this doesn't work. If there is some way I could do this, please let me know!

Comment: It's [postMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port), not sendMessage.

Comment: You are right! Still, I am getting a "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." error. Know why this might be?

Comment: Can't help without a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve).